# javascript variable initialization shows NaN

Tags: javascript, initialization, var

```
function sumArray(numbers){
  var sum;
  for(var i in numbers){
      sum += numbers[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumArray([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Hi all,

The outcome is **NaN**. However, if I initialize sum with **sum = 0**, the outcome is 15. Why JS does not recognize the value type in the array and do the initialization for me? Why does it return **NaN** in the first case?

Thanks

Comment: undefined+anything = NaN

Comment: Initialize `var sum = 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a variable is declared within current scope, it is initialized with `undefined` value.

```
var sum; // is initialized with undefined
```

In the `for` loop, the addition `sum += numbers[i]` is actually doing an `undefined + 1` operation. Because both operands are not string types, they are converted to numbers:

1. `undefined` + 1
2. `NaN` + 1
3. `NaN`

Please check this article for more info about [the addition operator](http://rainsoft.io/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/) (example 7).

Of course, to solve this problem just initialize it with 0:

```
var sum = 0;
```

Also I would sum the items simpler:

```
var sum = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce(function(sum, item) { 
  return sum + item; 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

when you create `var sum;` it's value is undefined [default]

so when you keep adding to undefined you get `NaN` [Not a Number]

but if you initialize as `var sum=0;`

then you are adding numbers to 0 so you get correct output

try

`console.log(undefined+1);` you get NaN but

if you do

`console.log(0+1);` then you get `1`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not initialized `sum`. So `sum+` will try to add to `undefined`.

```
    function sumArray(numbers){
      var sum=0;      // sum="" if you want output as 12345
      for(var i in numbers){
          sum += numbers[i];
      }
      return sum;
    }

console.log(sumArray([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/qxLoL04z/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind is very clear. When JavaScript finds any "undefined" or "unexpected" error then it returns NaN.

Where else in your second condition where you added sum=0 ,it already made a value of it then what ever you did it was addition to that value.